# Custom horizontal scrollbar mobile

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, scrollbar

Hi I've got a collection of buttons where users are able to scroll horizontally to see all of them. What I want to do is add a custom scrollbar so users know that you can scroll on this to see more buttons. This works on desktop but the scrollbar doesn't appear at all on mobile.

I've been searching online and can't see any solutions. Does anyone have an idea on how to get this working? Or alternative methods to give users the impression that they can scroll more to see more buttons.

```css
.container {display: flex; flex-direction: row; overflow-x: scroll; width: 300px;}
.variant {width: 250px; display: flex; color: grey; margin: 10px;}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track{-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); border-radius: 5px; background-color: #F5F5F5;}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar{width: 5px; height: 4px; background-color: #F5F5F5;}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{ border-radius: 5px; -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3); background-color: #555;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<button><span class="variant">Button</span></button>
<button><span class="variant">Button</span></button>
<button><span class="variant">Button</span></button>
<button><span class="variant">Button</span></button>
<button><span class="variant">Button</span></button>
<button><span class="variant">Button</span></button>
</div>
```